# Ubuntu compatible wireless trackball keyboard

Tags: keyboards, ubuntu

Im looking for compact **wireless** keyboard **with trackball** that would work with 12 or 14 **Ubuntu**. Ive searched on Q&A forums and didnt get answer ecxept most of them wouldnt work at all.

For example i was looking for something like that http://www.trust.com/en/product/17911-adura-wireless-multimedia-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a list of ELinux compatible keyboards [Here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Keyboards) there are quite a few with trackballs to choose from.

Specifically the LC-Power K1000BMW has been tested with Debian 6.0.04

I have also found that the [Emprex 9039ARF III](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Emprex-9039ARF-Wireless-Keyboard-Intergrated/dp/B00393P10E/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) has customer reviews that confirm its functionality in Ubuntu Squeeze as well as another version of linux that the customer did not specify

Lastly and probably your best option is the [IOGear 2.4GHz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004OBAJCA) as I was able to find CONFIRMED customer interaction specifically for Ubuntu compatibility.